# How to read text file full of json objects separated with space in python

Tags: python, json

I have a text file that have json objects in below format:

```
{owner:<value>, data:<value>}
{owner:<value>, data:<value>}
{owner:<value>, data:<value>}
{owner:<value>, data:<value>}
{owner:<value>, data:<value>}
```

Note that they are separated only by space. However, I know thay are all valid json objects containing the same keys.

How can I read this file in python and converting the file to a valid json file?

Note that the file is pretty big so I would need to read by streams.

Comment: Do you want a Big Json or N-Multiple Jsons for each line??

Comment: When you say they are separated by _space_, do you mean each object is on a **new line** (`\n`) or a different whitespace character?

Comment: I suspect it's a newline character. I have to check that. @damon

Comment: Ideally a big json file @Wonka

Comment: but that's not valid JSON, `owner` and `data` should be within `""`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to do this would be to read, process, and write each line of the output file as you go along.

```py
with open("input.data") as infile, open("output.json", "w") as outfile:
    first_line = True
    outfile.write("[")

    for line in infile:
        data = ""
        if first_line:
            first_line = False
        else:
            data += ","
        data += "\n  " + line.strip()
        outfile.write(data)

    outfile.write("\n]")
```

As an example, I tested this method in the python shell:

```py
>>> def write_lines_to_json(input_lines, indent="  "):
        yield "["

        first_line = True
        for line in input_lines:
            data = ""
            if first_line:
                first_line = False
            else:
                data += ","

            data += "\n" + indent + line.strip()
            yield data

        yield "\n]"

# This is the contents of the input file
>>> with open("/tmp/input.data") as fobj:
        print(fobj.read())
{"owner": "a", "data": 0}
{"owner": "b", "data": 1}
{"owner": "c", "data": 2}
{"owner": "d", "data": 3}
{"owner": "e", "data": 4}
{"owner": "f", "data": 5}
{"owner": "g", "data": 6}
{"owner": "h", "data": 7}
{"owner": "i", "data": 8}
{"owner": "j", "data": 9}

>>> with open("/tmp/input.data") as infile, open("/tmp/output.json", "w") as outfile:
        for data in write_lines_to_json(infile):
            outfile.write(data)

# This is the contents of the output json file
>>> with open("/tmp/output.json") as fobj:
        print(fobj.read())
[
  {"owner": "a", "data": 0},
  {"owner": "b", "data": 1},
  {"owner": "c", "data": 2},
  {"owner": "d", "data": 3},
  {"owner": "e", "data": 4},
  {"owner": "f", "data": 5},
  {"owner": "g", "data": 6},
  {"owner": "h", "data": 7},
  {"owner": "i", "data": 8},
  {"owner": "j", "data": 9}
]
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this, it will get a list with each json line:

```
import json
d = []

with open("file.txt") as f:
    lines = f.readlines()
    for line in lines:
        d.append(json.loads(line))
```

OUTPUT (should be)

```
d = [{owner:<value>, data:<value>},
     {owner:<value>, data:<value>},
     {owner:<value>, data:<value>},
     {owner:<value>, data:<value>}]
```